# SQL Query to get the last day of the month based on year and month passed

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL query to get the last calendar day of the 'month' and 'year'. It should provide the expected output based on the month and year passed to query.

Input:

```
DECLARE @MONTH NVARCHAR(3) = 'Apr'
DECLARE @yr_accting INT = '17'
```

(expected output : 30/4/2017).

Input:

```
DECLARE @MONTH NVARCHAR(3) = 'May'
DECLARE @yr_accting INT = '19'
```

(expected output : 31/5/2019).

Input:

```
DECLARE @MONTH NVARCHAR(3) = 'Nov'
DECLARE @yr_accting INT = '21'
```

(expected output : 30/11/2021).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONVERT` with style `6` to get a date from your text, then use `EOMONTH` to get the last day of the month.

```
SELECT EOMONTH(CONVERT(date, CONCAT('01 ', @MONTH, ' ', @yr_accting), 6));
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/saQ-0X_h)

I need not tell you that two-digit years are a terrible idea, as is storing a month in culture-specific string formats. Keep dates as dates, ie in binary format.